# combinatorics (check top cards of deck, if same color set aside and repeat, else stop)

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say you have a deck of

$z$ cards.

$x_1$ are white, $x_2$ are black and $y$ are blanks.

$n>0$ is given.

Now you do

1. Check top $n$ cards, if they all have the same color, put them aside and go back to 1. If they dont share the same color set them aside and stop.

How many cards will you set aside on average? How would the answer look like with $i$ different colors?

Now for a slightely different case:

1. check top $n$ cards, if they have the same color, lets call the color $c$, set them aside and go to 2, else set them aside and stop.
2. check top $n$ cards, set them aside, if they all have color $c$ go to 2., else stop.

I get the formula

$$n\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\lfloor{x_c/n}\rfloor} \dfrac{z-y}{z} \cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{(x_c-1)!}{(x_c-n\cdot j)!}}{\dfrac{(z-1)!}{(z-n\cdot j)!}}\right)$$
But with two or more colors I don't seem to find a closed form! Might just have to brute force?

Comment: why would you go any faster than $n=1$?

Comment: What do you mean? $n$ are the number of cards you check (if all of them have the same color) each step. Maybe "share" is confusing, its definately not the right word, I'll edit my post.

Comment: let n=1, you are guarenteed to satisfy the conditions. n=2+ and you are not.

Comment: Edited my post. $n$ is the number of cards you check in each step, if all of them share the color you set them aside and repeat, if not you set them aside and stop.

Comment: so can i choose n=1 then or not?

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake with the formula, correcting in a sec.

Comment: brilliant! so now i choose n=2

Comment: @Jon: You aren’t free to choose $n$: it’s one of the given parameters.

Comment: so why the constraint $n\gt1$?

Comment: Sorry I confused myself. I edited to describe correctly what the formula calculates (before it was wrong).

Comment: In the second version, the first step doesn't say what to do if the cards don't have the same colour?